# What other icons are there besides `favicon.ico` nowadays?

Tags: html, web, icons, favicon

I'm not following all the latest webdev trends so I've a question about what other icons besides `favicon.ico` a modern website should provide?

My current HTML looks like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon"          href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

My `favicon.ico` is 32x32 PNG file.

What other icons should I be providing for my new website? I guess there are icons for Android, OSX, Facebook (when you share your website?) and others.

Answer (score 0):

**Favicons in multiple sizes:**

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-l.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="64x64" href="favicon-xl.png">
```

*Note:* `16x16` and `32x32` are the most common ones; other sizes are unlikely to be used by major browsers.

**[iOS icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html):**

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

*Note 1:* these are [also used by Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926612/2170192).

*Note 2:* use `rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"` if you don't want iOS to apply the "glass-effect" and just show your image as-is.

**[Microsoft Windows 8.1 Tiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/05/21/support-a-live-tile-for-your-website-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1.aspx)**

```
<meta name="application-name" content="My Site"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/ms-tiny.png"/>
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/ms-square.png"/>
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/ms-wide.png"/>
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/ms-large.png"/>
```

*Note:* these are also used on Windows phones.

**Webpage thumbnail ([used by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) for example)**

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/preview-100x100.png" />
```

---

See also [this great article.](https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/)

Comment: Quick follow up question: What sizes should I provide my favicons? You mention 100x100, and 200x200. Who uses which sizes?

Comment: I've updated the answer; please read the article linked below for a lot of details on sizes, etc.

Comment: Follow up question: Do I've to implement all these images to be really top of the game?

Comment: It's a subjective question, and it depends on the type of your website. But, my personal opinion — **no, you don't need to implement all these images to be on top.** It is much more important to *provide great content*, and start refining the icons when you have no more important work to do on the content itself.

Comment: But of course it _may be important_ to implement _some of these,_ if you target a specific audience. E.g. if you target your website mostly at iPhone users, then it's of course important to provide `apple-touch-icon`.

Comment: Thanks as always Alex!